# Mono Project: How to install Mono framework on Red Hat Linux which is compiled on centOS?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, mono-framework

We have Red Hat Enterprise Linux servers at work place. However we dont have Red Hat Linux desktops. So I used CentOS 5.4 to compile the Mono sources and generated the Mono framework for CentOS and tested with some sample codes and I am satisfied. I want to transfer this compiled framework to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.

How Can I do that? Do I have to compile the Mono framework statically or do I have to copy the linked libraries as well? I am not familiar with linux much. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Triple post: http://serverfault.com/questions/120165 and http://superuser.com/questions/117286. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45726.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is a binary-compatible mirror of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  So if your desktop and the server line up exactly (32- vs 64-bit, same version [RHEL 5 update 4 vs CentOS 5.4], same RPMs installed), then it should be possible to just take the files you built on the CentOS machine and copy them to the corresponding location on the Red Hat machine, and it should just work.

Note that, ideally, you would build an RPM on the CentOS machine and then install the on the RHEL machine.  This way you don't have to worry about if you copied all the right files, and the RPM should encode enough dependency information to prevent the install from succeeding if the OS is incompatible.

Comment: @zach Thank you for your solution. how can I build RPM when I have only binaries?

Comment: First you'd need to copy all the binaries into a temporary directoy, but still in the same file structure as when installed (e.g. `/home/user/tmp-root/usr/bin/gcs`, etc).  Then you'd need to write an RPM spec file that doesn't do anything for the `%prep`, `%build`, and `%install` sections.  Then you would need to write the `%files` section so that all the files you staged somewhere are included in the RPM.  But the better way would be to just build the RPM from the mono sources---there might be a spec file included from mono upstream in the source tarball, or you can grab the one from RHEL.

Comment: If CentOS doesn't have it then RHEL won't have it. Grab the Fedora SRPMs and rebuild.

Comment: there is no SRPM too, however spec file is provided in tarball. With lots of iterations,I was able to generate the binary RPM. thank you

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is binary-compatible with RHEL at the same version, so after making sure that the dependencies are installed, copying the binaries will be enough.